# SQL time-series resampling

Tags: sql, time-series, clickhouse

I have clickhouse table with some rows like that

| id | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 6962098097124188161 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00 |
| 6968111372399976448 | 2022-07-02 00:00:00 |
| 6968111483775524864 | 2022-07-03 00:00:00 |
| 6968465518567268352 | 2022-07-04 00:00:00 |
| 6968952917160271872 | 2022-07-07 00:00:00 |
| 6968952924479332352 | 2022-07-09 00:00:00 |

I need to resample time-series and get count by date like this

| created_at | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-02 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2022-07-03 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2022-07-04 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 2022-07-05 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 2022-07-06 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 2022-07-07 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2022-07-08 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2022-07-09 00:00:00 | 6 |

I've tried this

```
SELECT 
  arrayJoin(
    timeSlots(
      MIN(created_at), 
      toUInt32(24 * 3600 * 10), 
      24 * 3600
    )
  ) as ts, 
  SUM(
    COUNT(*)
  ) OVER (
    ORDER BY 
      ts
  ) 
FROM 
  table
```

but it counts all rows.

How can I get expected result?

Comment: Which database do you use? SQL is a language, and *solution* depends on a *flavor*.

Comment: why not to just `group by`?

Answer (score 0):

why not use `group by created_at`

like

> select count(*) from table_name group by toDate(created_at)